# j_uasername & j_password no more used in Spring 3.2.5.RELEASE?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Are theses tow request parameters no more used in `Spring security` ? I am learning Spring Security and a whole day I was struggling with a simple Log in form. When I was submitting to the default /j_spring_security_check, which also appears not to be the default any more, I was redirected to `login?error` page so I decided to see what is going on after I check that the form parameters, and everything else was Ok. I submitted the form to my custom controller and I was able to read the `j_username` and `j_password` parameters. Then I decided to see what is going on in the Filter responsible for authentication in Spring

`org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`

```
 public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (postOnly && !request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
        }

        String username = obtainUsername(request);
        String password = obtainPassword(request);

        if (username == null) {
            username = "";
        }

        if (password == null) {
            password = "";
        }

        username = username.trim();

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

        // Allow subclasses to set the "details" property
        setDetails(request, authRequest);

        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }
```

I put breakpoints to check params and they were null ! then I checked `obtainUsername`/Password methods

```
  protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getParameter(usernameParameter);
    }
```

The `usernameParameter` and `passwordParameter` were `username` & `password`, respectively rather than `j_username` & `j_password`

[image]

here is my [pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/AdelinGhanaem/6a21e7286090e8e00ae2)

Comment: It is still very much there, also `usernamepasswordauthenticationfilter ` comes from `spring-security-web` jar, refer [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) for more

Comment: Ok, I will post a screenshoot :)

Comment: post your pom.xml also

Comment: @ankur-singhal I updated the question you can check pom.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you got as far as looking at that class, you should also be able to see that the default values are `j_username` and `j_password`. However, it's also possible to override them, which will depend on how you've configured your application.

If you've used Java configuration, then it does [override the defaults](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/FormLoginConfigurer.html#usernameParameter%28java.lang.String%29).

Rather than struggling to build something from scratch, you should start with a working sample. There are lots of samples in the Spring Security source tree. For example, here is the [login form](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/samples/form-jc/src/main/resources/views/login.html#L17) from one of them, in which you can also easily see that different parameter names are used.

Comment: maybe you are right. But I really did not override any parameters.

Comment: I didn't say you did - I said if you use Java configuration it overrides the defaults which are defined in the filter. If read the Javadoc link, it tells you the values it uses. Since you don't say anything about how you've configured your app, it's impossible to say for sure where it happens, but that's the most likely reason.

Comment: You are 100% right ! I do use Java Config approach.